# Can I still use ADO.net when I develop in asp.net mvc or should I completely adapt to EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I’m trying to learn to develop using asp.net mvc. but yea, using the EF style is quite different than what I’m used to and that is the ADO. What I wanna know is, should I really use the EF approach, or could I still use the ADO approach. I just wanna know what’s better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328889/entityframework-vs-pure-ado-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270124/entity-framework-vs-ado-net

Comment: *"I just wanna know what's better"* = opinion based response = off-topic for SO.  Both have their advantages or you could use another ORM such as nHibernate.  *"Can you use ADO"* (as per question title) - obviously otherwise you wouldn't be asking which is better.

Answer (score 2):

> I just wanna know what’s better

Depends on your definition of "better".

Inform yourself about Entity Framework, about its strong and weak points (especially the weak points!), experiment with it, and if you feel that it will really help you to save time and produce good quality code, then by any means use it. If not, there's absolutely nothing wrong with using plain old ADO.NET (altough using a tool like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) certainly helps in this case).